# Removing and Adding CSS Class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I've an area which I'd like to add an CSS animation to when it's clicked, and then bring it back with another animation when it's loading.

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap's tabs and turned on the "fade" transition between the tabs, but want to specifically animate something inside of those tabs while they're switching. I don't want to mess with the root J.S. code there so I'll just settle with a work around.

Heres my code:

```
   $(".tabit").click(function (){

        //Drop Center Icon on click
        if ($('.centericon').hasClass('fadeInDown')) {
            $(".centericon").removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("fadeOutDown").delay(100).queue(function(next){
                $(this).removeClass("fadeOutDown").addClass("fadeInDown");
                });
        }
        else{
            $(".centericon").addClass("fadeOutDown").delay(100).queue(function(next){
                $(this).removeClass("fadeOutDown").addClass("fadeInDown");
                });
        }
    });
```

The .centericon class is repeated, so after 1 click, multiple instances will have the "fadeInDown" class. Works fine when I click one time, but if I click twice, then the .centericon only gets class .fadeOutDown.

Comment: When you use `$(".centericon").hasClass`, it will grab the first element found by the selector and see if it has the class. You might be looking for `$(this).find(".centericon")` but I don't know your HTML structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".tabit").click(function (){
        //Scroll to top when navigating through tabs

        //Drop Center Icon on click
        if ($('.centericon').hasClass('fadeInDown')) {
            $(".centericon").removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("fadeOutDown");
            $(".centericon").delay(100).queue(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeOutDown');
                $(this).dequeue();

            });
            $(".centericon").delay(100).removeClass('fadeOutDown').addClass("fadeInDown");
        }
        else{
            $(".centericon").addClass("fadeOutDown");
            $(".centericon").delay(100).queue(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('fadeOutDown').addClass("fadeInDown");
                $(this).dequeue();

            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Change `click` to `toggle`

```
$(".tabit").toggle(function () {
    $(".centericon").removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass("fadeOutDown").delay(100).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeOutDown").addClass("fadeInDown");
    });
}, function () {
    $(".centericon").addClass("fadeOutDown").delay(100).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).removeClass("fadeOutDown").addClass("fadeInDown");
    });
});
```

Comment: this method is deprecated from version: 1.8 and removed from : 1.9 onwards.